# Is there a password_reset hook in frappe framework?

Tags: frappe

I have a requirement where i want an item for a doctype to be created when the user signup.

i can use ‘[on_session_creation](https://frappeframework.com/docs/v13/user/en/python-api/hooks#session-hooks)’ hook which gets called when the user logs into the system for the very first time aka while creating a new login session and validate whether the first item has been created for that user or not. this is working fine.

but, I have a flow where the user can signup via email and when they tap on the confirmation link in their email, the system asks them to reset the password. In this flow, the system is automatically logging in the user and also the ‘on_session_creation’ hook is not getting called.

Is there anyway for me to create an item in the doctype only when the user signup?

Or to put my question in another way:
Is there a way for me to stop the session from getting created when the user resets their password for the first time when they do so via the signup confirmation link?

Comment: Have you tried using the `on_login` hook instead of the `on_session_creation` hook?

Comment: @NikhilKothari `on_login` gets called only upon login and not during password reset